# Using JSON for solving for Cross Domain issues

Tags: ajax

JavaScript-based AJAX seemed a good approach until we hit the limitation of AJAX clients only being able to communicate to the server from where they are downloaded, thus adhering to the "same origin policy."

Could anybody please tell me how can a JSON could solve this  cross domain problem , as in my knowledge JSON is only a data format saying how the data can be presented .

Please give your advices on this 
My question is how an XMLHttprequest is controlled by a data format of different structure

Answer (score 2):

See [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) on Wikipedia:

> JSONP or "JSON with padding" is a complement to the base JSON data
>   format, a pattern of usage allowing a page to request data from a
>   server in a different domain. JSONP is a solution to this problem,
>   forming an alternative to a more recent method called Cross-Origin
>   Resource Sharing.

...

> The server then wraps its JSON response with this prefix, or "padding", before sending it to the browser. When the browser receives the wrapped response from the server it is now a script, rather than simply a data declaration.

Answer (score 1):

See this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) post. It does show you how/why. But to be accurate:

It works, because it's not json anymore, but because it's interpreted as script/javascript

Comment: Thanks!!! May I ask this question, as a server-side programmer -- if I have both domains on the same server - would it be possible if I used symbolic-link of file pointing to other file?  Would it be an acceptable practice or not?  Or would the method as Wiki indicates be the best?

Answer (score 0):

Hardly as elegant as the jsonp answers, but with at added bonuses of:

- Makes it possible to query servers that are not jsonp "aware".
- Possible server-side data-validation.

My line of thought goes toward writing a script on your own server that would proxy the requests and responses.

In this way you could also validate the contents of the data.

Moreover jsonp requires the requested server to encapsulate its json response in a callback-function. This solution is agnostic to wether the queried server is jsonp capable.

(edit):
Of course it would be wise to make sure, that the script doesn't allow everybody to proxy everything :)